# kubernetes - setting up a public available cluster

Tags: kubernetes

So I got a running cluster on my server. The server is running `ubuntu 18.06`. I set up the cluster using `kubeadm`, `kubectl` and `kubelet`.

**My goal in a nutshell: I want to reach the services with executing `http://myserver.com/service`.**

I am kinda lost with exposing the services to port 8080. The current structure is like this:

> 31001:SERVICE:8080 -> 8080:POD

So I need to redirect the requests incoming using `http://myserver.com/service` to the `kubernetes service` with port 31001.

Current situation: I can only access the cluster via server IP:6443.

So my question: how can I make the cluster more or less public available on port 8080?

Comment: It's not realy clear what complicates you, so I can suggest you to have a look at this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/), I guess it explains the idea pretty well.

Comment: HTTP defaults to port 80, not port 31001.

Comment: Is this server hosted in the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the tutorial @getslaf provided, there are few ways to achieve your goal but the best practice would be to configure an [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource).

Ingress can provide load balancing capabilities, SSL termination, and name-based virtual hosting.

I think the two most common choices would be [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/) or [Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) but as far as I know, there are other choices.